# How to auto create a new row in a table every day or according to date django

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

```
# modaly.py
class User(modals.Modal): name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Traffic(models.Model): my_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  per_day_user_visit = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True) traffic_date = models.DateField(auto_created=True)
```

| id | my_user | per_day_user_visit | traffic_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | instance | 500 user_visit | monday |
| 2 | instance | 512 user_visit | tuesday |

```
# views.py
# Auto created a new row, when new day come
if newday:
    Traffic.objects.create(my_user = "1", per_day_user_visit = "512", date=datetime.now())
```

Comment: You can create a celery task for it and run it with celerybeat once per day.

Comment: This isn't something you would do in django as this is a scheduled job. It is better done by a job scheduler. Mysql has a built-in one using create event, you can use whatever scheduler the OS comes with (cron or windows task scheduler as examples) or you can use a pyton based one, like celery. Which one you choose depends on your exact requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to increment a visit each time the user hits the view, I suggest something like:

```py
from django.utils import timezone
today = timezone.now().date()

traffic, created = Traffic.objects.get_or_create(
    my_user=1,
    date=today,
    defaults={"per_day_user_visit":0}
)

# Now do whatever you need with your traffic object, for example:
traffic.per_day_user_visit += 1
traffic.save()
```

⚠️ You may have performance issues to proceed this way, if your users are very active.

Also, you won't have an entry for days where the user didn't visit. The `get_or_create` part could be triggered through a cron or celerybeat somehow if you need an entry for every day, as suggested in the comments.